# How to implement delayed/batched table view update from NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

[The documentation says:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008228-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

> You should consider carefully whether you want to update the table view as each change is made. If a large number of modifications are made simultaneously—for example, if you are reading data from a background thread— /.../ you could just implement controllerDidChangeContent: (which is sent to the delegate when all pending changes have been processed) to reload the table view.

This is exactly what I'm doing: I'm processing incoming changes in a background thread with a different ManagedObjectContext, and merge the results into the main thread MOC with mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:. So far so good.

I chose to not implement controller:didChangeObject:... and would instead like to do the batched update that the document suggests.

Question/problem: the document doesn't elaborate how to actually implement the batched update? Should I just call [tableview reloadData] in controllerDidChangeContent: or is there a less intrusive way that saves me from a full reload?

One thought I have: I could take note of mergeChangesFrom... notification that contains the changed objects, figure out their indexpaths, and just call tableview:ReloadRowsAtIndexPaths: for them. But is there any authoritative info, recommendations or examples? Or just [tableview reloadData]?

(Aside: controller:didChangeObject:... started behaving really erratically when it received a set of batched updates, even though the same updating code [that I now put in background thread] was fine before when it was running on the main thread, but of course locking up the UI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call `reloadData` in `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

For animating individual changes to the table, Apple's boiler plate code (iOS SDK 4.3.x) looks like this:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type)
    {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: Sigh... if that's what it comes down to :(

Comment: The reloadData is a good solution when the numbers of objects that changed is big. But how can you know that? In my case, i'd like to be able to know how many changes have been detected so that I can decide if i want a full reloadData or smooth animated updates.

Comment: @DirtyHenry I have added the boiler plate code for handling the animated updates. I imagine the NSFetchedResultsController calls these methods after you call `save` on your managed object context. So, you should see how many records changed before you call `save`. If it's above your threshold, just call `reloadData` instead of `endUpdates` in `controllerDidChangeContent:` (and return at the top of the other delegate methods).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

Instead of calling

- `deleteSections`
- `insertSections`
- `reloadSections`
- `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`
- `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`
- `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

as the changes are coming in at `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath`, collect the indexPaths and sections in properties. Then execute the batch in `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

Ref: http://www.fruitstandsoftware.com/blog/2013/02/19/uitableview-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller-updates-done-right/

**Edit**

Here is a slightly different, more contrived, but also more compact, version of the approach mentioned in the link:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sectionChanges;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *objectChanges;

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
  didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    NSMutableDictionary *sectionChange = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            sectionChange[@(type)] = @(sectionIndex);
            break;
    }

    [self.sectionChanges addObject:sectionChange];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *objectChange = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            objectChange[@(type)] = newIndexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            objectChange[@(type)] = indexPath;
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            objectChange[@(type)] = @[indexPath, newIndexPath];
            break;
    }

    [self.objectChanges addObject:objectChange];        
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    NSUInteger totalChanges = self.sectionChanges.count + self.objectChanges.count;

    if (totalChanges > 0)
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];

        if (self.sectionChanges.count > 0)
        {
            for (NSDictionary *change in self.sectionChanges)
            {
                [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                    NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];

                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                            [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                            [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                            [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[obj unsignedIntegerValue]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
        else if (self.objectChanges > 0)
        {
            NSMutableArray *indexPathsForUpdatedObjects = [NSMutableArray new];

            for (NSDictionary *change in self.objectChanges)
            {
                [change enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                    NSFetchedResultsChangeType type = [key unsignedIntegerValue];
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[obj] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[obj] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                            [indexPathsForUpdatedObjects addObject:obj];
                            //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[obj] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                            break;
                        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                            [tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:obj[0] toIndexPath:obj[1]];
                            break;
                    }
                }];
            }

            [tableView endUpdates];

            for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPathsForUpdatedObjects)
                if ([tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath])
                    [self updateCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
        }

        [self.sectionChanges removeAllObjects];
        [self.objectChanges removeAllObjects];

    }
    else if (totalChanges < 1)
    {
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray *)sectionChanges
{
    if (!_sectionChanges)
        _sectionChanges = [NSMutableArray new];

    return _sectionChanges;
}
- (NSMutableArray *)objectChanges
{
    if (!_objectChanges)
        _objectChanges = [NSMutableArray new];

    return _objectChanges;
}
```

*Note that this solution is not perfect in that it does not update objects if there are changes to sections and those objects are in a section that is not updated. Should be easy to fix (and is irrelevant for many applications).*

Answer (score 0):

You could note the last index path in your datasource & then do this -

```
    NSIndexPath *indexPath     = nil;
    NSMutableArray *newResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(gLastResultIndex < [self.dataSource count])
    {
        for(int i=(gLastResultIndex); i<[self.dataSource count]; i++)
        {
            indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            [newResults addObject:indexPath];
        }
        [self.table beginUpdates];
        [self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newResults withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.table endUpdates];
    }
    [newResults release];
```

This is selectively adding new rows to your existing `UITableView`. reload table reloads all cells in your table which you might not need. I use reload table only when the entire datasource changes...